# How To Map Fn+Key (Multiple Keys) To Other Key in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, thinkpad, hotkeys

I've got a ThinkPad W530 laptop, which replaces the Application Key (also known as Menu Key or Mouse Right Click key, usually between Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> and Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) with the Print Screen key.

So, I need to replace <kbd>Prt/Scr</kbd> with Application key. That's easy, all key mapping software like SharpKeys or whatever can do that. There are even a few threads in SuperUser about dozen of those.

But then, the different part to this question from the others (which is why it's not a duplicate, I think) is that I also don't want to completely lose the <kbd>Prt/Scr</kbd> key. I'm thinking about replacing it with either:

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Prt/Scr</kbd>
- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>

These seemed to have no special meaning, so, I'm not overriding anything, just adding functionality to either of them (one of them, not both), to be the new <kbd>Prt/Scr</kbd> key.

I couldn't find any key mapping software that can detect or let me select more than one key to map, even when the other key is something like <kbd>Fn</kbd> key (although they all can map <kbd>Fn</kbd> key itself, without combination).

I know it may make sense why this restriction exists, but it'll be really useful if I can override it though.
Do you know any program that can do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it is not possible due to the hardware design of `Fn` key, I suggest using following key maps to solve your current problem:

```
PrtScr --> AppKey
shift+PrtScr --> PrtScr
```

You can easily achieve this by using AutoHotKey.

Comment: As per AutoHotKey docs, it seems registry mapping cannot involve multiple keys like Shift, etc. + other key, so, looks like AutoHotKey is the way to go. Got it configured as per your advice and set as a Scheduled Task on login, worked nicely. Thanks.