# Reprogramming Keyboard to Create Right Click

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> button on my keyboard that is between my <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons.

I would like to reprogram <kbd>Fn</kbd> to do a right-click as you would on your mouse. Is there a way on Windows to reprogram the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to create a right-click shortcut?

Comment: What version of Windows? Is it a built-in keyboard of a Laptop? If so, no; if it's an external, it *may* be possible, depending on the keyboard. Do you have the Context Menu button on your keyboard? I'd think that would be better for the Right Click

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: Probably not.

**Long answer**...

The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is generally found on laptops and other small-form factor keyboards. In most It is not sent to or processed by the OS, but rather internally to the keyboard to get functions there just aren't enough physical keys for.

Similar questions have been asked across the Stack Exchange network, and none of the other answers were hopeful either:

[Intercepting the Fn key on laptops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514781/intercepting-the-fn-key-on-laptops) from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) indicates that some laptops (Lenovos are specifically mentioned) have a BIOS option to completely change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key functionality.

I've personally used machines that let you swap the behavior of <kbd>Fn</kbd> from "Press with the other key to get the regular function, get the special function without it" to "Press with the other key to get the special function, get the regular function with it".

[Remap FN to another key](https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key) - This one is Logitech-specific, so your question isn't quite a duplicate... unless you have a Logitech keyboard, anyway.

Comment: I don't have a laptop. Its a logitech.

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide a model number to your specific keyboard, we could more adequately answer your question.  the Fn key on laptops is usually not accessible by the operating system (it is processed by the BIOS to enable modifiers) but on most Logitech keyboards it is customizable.  See if the Logitech Gaming Software is available for your keyboard first, for full compatibility.

http://support.logitech.com/en-us/software/lgs

Setpoint is a Logitech program available for older peripherals.

https://www.logitech.com/en-us/articles/11650

Otherwise, there are a plethora of keyboard button remapping softwares available (e.g. Key Remapper, KeyExtender, Remap, a Google search will turn up numerous results.)

Comment: I am using the k520

Comment: You can download and install Logitech SetPoint from the following link.  Please remember to up-vote good answers.
http://support.logitech.com/en_roeu/product/wireless-combo-mk520#download

Comment: @jessica You should add that information to the question. Plus, what Raj said. :)

Comment: heh I'm the upvoter for TJL's comment, he acknowledges my answer, but despite being correct it isn't liked.  I do not understand this forum.