# Overwrite Fn key functionality Windows11

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, hotkeys, fn-key

I want to use the `Fn` hot keys implemented in Visual Studio (and other programs as well) but it seems that the `Fn` keys have different default options on my laptop that have higher priority than program hotkeys. E.g., `F11` increases the system sound, but I want to use `F11` in the Visual Studio debugger to go to the next line. Does someone know how to tell the system that the hot keys assigned by a program should have higher priority than the default key assignment?

Comment: what is the brand and type of your laptop?

Comment: Make sure you turn on/off the Function mode (Fn button) before hitting those keys

Comment: @MátéJuhász It is an Acer Aspire 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you need to change BIOS settings for the desired behaviour

> You need to go to BIOS to change FN behavior. By default, it set to Media which you need to change to function.
> To enter in BIOS, press f2 key without fn key, and after entering in BIOS, change function key behavior and then press f10 without fn. Now you have reversed fn key.

https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/610406/how-do-i-reverse-fn-key-on-my-acer-aspire-a715-75g

Comment: Ah, very nice, thank you! (I actually just now understand what the Fn key is for)

Answer (score 1):

According to MS documentation the Fn keys generally cannot be remapped as these are not keys the OS generally understands.

Similar to question [https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key#:~:text=So%20the%20real%20deal%20about,fn%2Dkey%20is%20not%20feasible](https://superuser.com/questions/65/remap-fn-to-another-key#:%7E:text=So%20the%20real%20deal%20about,fn%2Dkey%20is%20not%20feasible).

The standard F1~F12 keys can.
I have used Windows PowerToys to successfully remap the non Fn keys.